# Tratar InputMismatchException calculadora

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, exceção

Eu estou fazendo uma calculadora em java oo, e gostaria de tratar essa exceção mas não sei como.

Essa e a classe principal.

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Calculadora calc = null;

        int opc = -1, num1, num2;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.println("Entre com o primeiro numero: ");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Entre com o segundo numero: ");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();

            menu();
            opc = sc.nextInt();


switch (opc) {

        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:

             calc = new Calculadora(new Soma(), num1, num2);
             System.out.println("\nResultado: " + calc);

            break;

        case 2:

            calc = new Calculadora(new Subtracao(), num1, num2);
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + calc + "\n");

            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Opcao Invalida.");

            break;
    }


        } while(opc != 0);
    }

    static void menu() {

        System.out.println("\tEscolha uma Opcao ");
        System.out.println("0: Sair");
        System.out.println("1: Somar");
        System.out.println("2: Subtracao");
        System.out.print("Opcao: ");

    }
}
```

Comment: InputMismatchException ocorre quando a entrada de dado não condiz com o tipo esperado, tipo, nesse código seu, espera-se que se entre com inteiros, se digitar um caractere, lança a exceção. Trate todas as entradas como String e valide através de parse se são realmente digitos, dessa forma você contorna a exceção.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Precisa realmente de uma classe calculadora? Ok. Tem várias formas de tratar a exceção, vou apresentar uma delas, onde ele entende que algo digitado errado deve desconsiderar e entrar novamente com o dado, não importa onde foi o erro, mas dá para sofisticar. Fiz assim:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Entre com o primeiro numero: ");
                int num1 = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Entre com o segundo numero: ");
                int num2 = sc.nextInt();
                menu(); //completa desnecessidade fazer isso
                int opc = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException) {
                System.out.println("Você digitou algo irregular, vamos começar de novo");
                continue;
            }
            switch (opc) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                     System.out.println("\nResultado: " + new Calculadora(new Soma(), num1, num2));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Resultado: " + new Calculadora(new Subtracao(), num1, num2) + "\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcao Invalida.");
                    break;
            }
        } while (opc != 0);
    }

    static void menu() {
        System.out.println("\tEscolha uma Opcao ");
        System.out.println("0: Sair");
        System.out.println("1: Somar");
        System.out.println("2: Subtracao");
        System.out.print("Opcao: ");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Calculator2.java).

Dei uma melhorada no código como um todo. Não pude testar porque não foi feito um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Aproveito para dizer que não gosto como o Java trata entrada de dados errados. Particularmente prefiro fazer sem o uso de exceção e tratar o erro individualmente pelo fluxo normal. Dá mais trabalho, mas fica melhor. Mas isso não é o jeito do Java trabalhar, ainda que possa ser feito normalmente.

Pra fazer direito, na prática teria que escrever sua própria rotina de *parser* para evitar a exceção.

Comment: Ele pula as outras entradas, só tratando uma por vez.

Comment: Não sei o que isso quer dizer.